Overridden delete operator does not work if object has been assigned to a variable
When I override the delete operator and then delete an object that has been assigned to a variable Blender does not use the overriding function. If I do not assign it, my function is being used.
Here is a minimal working example for the default scene with the cube being selected.
def delete_plot_object(obj):
    print("Using custom delete function.")
bpy.types.Object.__del__ = delete_plot_object

my_cube = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]
bpy.ops.object.delete()

However, without a variable assignment it works:
def delete_plot_object(obj):
    print("Using custom delete function.")
bpy.types.Object.__del__ = delete_plot_object

bpy.ops.object.delete()

I don't see any reason why a simple variable assignment would make such a difference.

Why do you want to do this? Why not just delete the objects in a way it's usually done? Actually, what is it exactly that you want to do here?

I am not entirely sure what is happening here, but I don't think you can call this overriding delete operator. I believe, delete operator might not be written in Python, you just call it from the Python API if I understand it correctly and you are changing "magic" method, not the operator... I don't think you should be doing this, whatever it is that you want to achieve.

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1481512/10259287 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/8689983/10259287 so this works in Python, but you are not using only Python here, you are just using Python API to control Blender. You should provide more context and describe the actual goal and problem you want to solve. This is an XY problem.

i think this "del is called when the garbage collector happens to be collecting the objects, not when you lose the last reference to an object and not when you execute del object." is the most interesting statement of Martynas links regarding your question. So short: just don't do it.

I need to keep track of certain meshes in my scene. When they are deleted I need to perform some book keeping.
It is true that the delete operator is not entirely overwritten. However, I can use this to perform additional tasks when my objects are deleted.

The reason is simple, When you assign the Cube to my_cube and remove it from the scene, the object my_cube still here, so it not trigger __del__

Makes sense @XY. Looks like modifying the del function has been the wrong approach.
